# Where is offset of consumer stored in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, offset, kafka-topic

In Kafka, I know that there is a topic, named `__consumer_offsets`, which is used to store the offsets of consumers. As my understanding, a consumer will do two kinds of things:

1. fetch data from partition.
2. write the offsets to the topic `__consumer_offsets`.

After reading this link: https://www.learningjournal.guru/courses/kafka/kafka-foundation-training/offset-management/, I knew that there were two kinds of offsets for a Kafka consumer: the current offset and the committed offset.

I've read many docs and blogs of Kafka, but it seems that all descriptions about offsets of consumer are about the committed offset. For example, `enable.auto.commit=true` will make the consumer write the committed offset to the topic `__consumer_offsets` automatically and the function `commitSync()` can manually write the committed offset to the topic `__consumer_offsets`.

Now I want to know how Kafka processes the current offset. Will it be write into the topic `__consumer_offsets` too? How? When?

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64775491/does-kafka-distinguish-between-consumed-offset-and-commited-offset/64776504#64776504) might help you to understand. Your client will keep up of the *consumed* offsets per partition and you can shift it around with APIs such as `seek`. Nothing about a *consumed* offset is written into an internal topic.

Comment: And in summary, it's just retained in memory by the client code and used when fetching the next batch. That's why when a consumer goes there is no record of what it had consumed other than the committed offset hence at least once semantics - a consumer may process records and then fail before committing.